Hiding content in Divi using custom conditions
I have Divi on my Wordpress site and my site is displayed in a Webview in an iOS and Android app which use custom user agents 'LMV iOS App' and 'LMV Android App'.
I have written some code so that on rows and columns (can't get modules to work), there is a tab on the Divi Builder called LMV App with 2 toggles, one for Hide in iOS App and one for Hide in Android App. I want to make it so that if these conditions are enabled then the content in that row/section/module is hidden for that specific user agent.
I will post my code below:
/**
 * Extends Divi's Visual Builder to add custom LMV App settings.
 */

function lmv_custom_divi_editor() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return;
    }

    add_action('et_builder_framework_loaded', function() {
        // Add the main tab
        add_filter('et_builder_main_tabs', 'add_lmv_app_tab', 1);
        
        // Add configuration fields for the section, row, and module
        add_filter('et_pb_all_fields_unprocessed_et_pb_section', 'add_lmv_app_config');
        add_filter('et_pb_all_fields_unprocessed_et_pb_row', 'add_lmv_app_config');
        add_filter('et_pb_all_fields_unprocessed_et_pb_module', 'add_lmv_app_config');

        // Filter to modify output based on the user agent
        add_filter('et_pb_module_output', 'conditionally_hide_module', 99, 3);
        add_filter('et_pb_row_output', 'conditionally_hide_row', 99, 3);
        add_filter('et_pb_section_output', 'conditionally_hide_section', 99, 3);
    });
}

// Add the LMV App tab
function add_lmv_app_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['lmv_app_tab'] = esc_html__('LMV App', 'lmv-rental');
    return $tabs;
}

// Add configuration fields for the section, row, and module
function add_lmv_app_config($fields_unprocessed) {
    // Check if the current tab is the LMV App tab
    if (isset($fields_unprocessed['lmv_app_settings'])) {
        return $fields_unprocessed; // Return early if the fields are already set
    }

    $fields = [];

    // Add a toggle for iOS settings
    $fields['lmv_ios_settings_label'] = [
        'label'           => esc_html__('Hide in iOS App', 'lmv-rental'),
        'type'            => 'yes_no_button',
        'option_category' => 'configuration',
        'options'         => [
            'off' => esc_html__('No', 'lmv-rental'),
            'on'  => esc_html__('Yes', 'lmv-rental'),
        ],
        'default'         => 'off',
        'description'     => esc_html__('Hide this in the iOS App.', 'lmv-rental'),
        'tab_slug'        => 'lmv_app_tab',
    ];

    // Add a toggle for Android settings
    $fields['lmv_android_settings_label'] = [
        'label'           => esc_html__('Hide in Android App', 'lmv-rental'),
        'type'            => 'yes_no_button',
        'option_category' => 'configuration',
        'options'         => [
            'off' => esc_html__('No', 'lmv-rental'),
            'on'  => esc_html__('Yes', 'lmv-rental'),
        ],
        'default'         => 'off',
        'description'     => esc_html__('Hide this in the Android App.', 'lmv-rental'),
        'tab_slug'        => 'lmv_app_tab',
    ];

    // Merge the new fields with the existing fields
    $fields_unprocessed = array_merge($fields_unprocessed, $fields);

    return $fields_unprocessed;
}

// Conditionally hide module content
function conditionally_hide_module($output, $props, $render_slug) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'LMV iOS App') !== false && !empty($props['lmv_ios_settings_label']) && $props['lmv_ios_settings_label'] === 'on') {
        return ''; // Hide the content
    }
    return $output;
}

// Conditionally hide row content
function conditionally_hide_row($output, $props, $render_slug) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'LMV iOS App') !== false && !empty($props['lmv_ios_settings_label']) && $props['lmv_ios_settings_label'] === 'on') {
        return ''; // Hide the content
    }
    return $output;
}

// Conditionally hide section content
function conditionally_hide_section($output, $props, $render_slug) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'LMV iOS App') !== false && !empty($props['lmv_ios_settings_label']) && $props['lmv_ios_settings_label'] === 'on') {
        return ''; // Hide the content
    }
    return $output;
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'lmv_custom_divi_editor');


I have tried so many variations of code and cannot figure it out
